# How to run NUnit 2 tests in visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, visual-studio-2022, nunit-2.6

I am trying to execute NUnit tests on a legacy project in Visual Studio 2022 professional. Migrating from NUnit 2 to NUnit 3 is not yet an option, and part of the team works with Visual Studio 2019. The problem I am facing is that the tests are not executed by VS 2022, without any error message on the attempt.

The test explorer displays the following after executing the test (and the console output finishes with a successful build):

[image: Test Explorer]

The NuGet Package manager had NUnit 2.6.1 already installed. I additionally installed the packets `NUnit.Extension.NUnitV2Driver` and `NUnit.Extension.NUnitV2ResultWriter`. A test adapter seems only available for NUnit3 (`NUnit3TestAdapter`, which I also installed). I enabled all the packages for the individual project as was commented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70434300/14627587). Is there anything else to install/configure that I could be missing to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a few suggested approaches...

The NUnit3TestAdapter, as the name indicates, is designed for NUnit 3. While it is able to run NUnit3 tests by use of the NUnitV2Driver extension, I don't think that will work under Visual Studio just by installing the package. You could experiment by modifying the `.addins` file installed along with the the adapter, but I can't give you precise instructions as I haven't tried it.

BTW, the V2 driver extension produces output in V3 format, which is probably what you want for use under Visual Studio. The V2 result writer is only needed if you have a reason to want an output file in V2 format.

I think your best bet may be to try using the last release of the NUnitTestAdapter (i.e. without '3' in the name), which **only** works with NUnit V2. If it will load under VS2022, it should do exactly what you want. In that case, you should stop loading the two extensions, which the V2 runner doesn't support.

Comment: Uninstalling all packages except `NUnit` and installing `NUnitTestAdapter` worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One small detail for me was that up through Visual Studio 2019, the NUnitTestAdapter was installed through Extensions -> Manage Extensions. In Visual Studio 2022, it actually gets added on the test project by right clicking on the references and then Manage NuGet Packages, then browsing for the NUnitTestAdapter. Once I did that, the text explorer would execute the NUnit 2tests.